# How to use SUBSTITUTE if the text contains " inside

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I use the SUBSTITUTE formula if the text to be substituted contains a `"`? For example, if I want to change `Hello"Bye` to an empty string:

- Assume `Cell A1`: `Hello"Bye`

I have tried both

- `B1=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Hello"Bye","")`

and

- `B1=SUBSTITUTE(A1,""Hello"Bye"","")`

Both result in an error because there is a `"` in the middle of the text confused with the `"` from the formula.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can escape `"` by doubling it:

`SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Hello""Bye","")`

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, but can make the line more difficult to read (especially if you have multiple string concatenations).

As an alternative, you can add the specific ASCII value of the character using the `char()` function. 34 is the ASCII value for a double quote - `char(34)`.

For example, a cell formula `="Hello""Bye"` can also be represented as `="Hello" & char(34) & "Bye"`.

Comment: IMHO this makes it even hard to read, because you also need to know what char34 is.